# Dynamically Create Route aliases in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, alias, rails-routing

Some of my customers want to create aliases for certain pages in Rails. An example of this kind of alias is displayed below:

```
match '/events_nl' => 'pages#show', :defaults => { :id => '1' , :locale => "nl"}
```

We are using rails admin so what if I create a table with the fields for manual alias creation:

- alias
- controller
- id
- locale

Some models have already an alias in in the table let's call it model Page. Model Page has a field alias is it possible to do something like this in the routes:

```
pages_with_alias = Page.find_all_by_alias(true)
pages_with_alias.each do page
  match page.alias , :to "pages#show", :defaults => { :id => page.id  , :locale => page.locale}
end
```

**Question:**
I'm just looking for the most rails like way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of my dear Friend sevenseacat everything worked out great:

What did I do:

**1)Added the needed Alias fields/columns to table**

**2)Created the Alias model / controller**
*This code is pseudo code but you will get the picture*

```
  def show
    object = Model.where("lower(alias) =?", params[:alias].downcase).first || OtherModel.where("lower(alias) =?", params[:alias].downcase).first
    if object.class.name == "Model"
      @model = Model.find_by_id!(object.model_id)
      render "model/show"
    elsif object.class.name == "OtherModel"
      @othermodel = OtherModel.find_by_id!(object.othermodel_id)

      I18n.locale = object.locale
      render "othermodel/show"
    else
      not_found
    end
  end
```

**3)Created the route**

```
get '*alias', to: 'alias#show', as: 'alias'
```

**Just for information not_found:**

```
  def not_found
    raise ActionController::RoutingError.new(t("activemodel.errors.messages.not_found"))
  end
```

**Note 1**

This is without the cross table validation

Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: I know it's just pseudo-code but keep it consistent - one clause uses `where(id: foo).first` and the other uses `find_by_id!` - the first can possibly just return nil, which will blow up when rendering the view.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this would be with a wildcard route at the end of your routes file, something like:

```
get '*alias', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
```

Which, for any URL that doesn't match any other routes, will call your PagesController's show action with the path in the `alias` parameter.

Then inside the show action, you can do a `Page.find_by_alias!(params[:alias])` - if no page matches, you will get a standard 404 page (because an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception will be thrown), and if the page does exist, then you can continue as normal.

edit:

For multiple models that you want to alias like this, you might instead point your wildcard to a different controller, and then in that controller iterate through your models looking for one that matches. eg. first `Page.find_by_alias(params[:alias])`.... if its nil, then `Testimonial.find_by_alias(params[:alias])`, etc..... when you find one that matches, then you can render the appropriate view.

Of course, if you do this, you run the risk of naming collisions - what happens if you have a Testimonial and a Page with the same alias? One will never be viewable, because the other one will be looked up and matched first.

Comment: Hi Sevenseacat, As told before this works all very well for 1 model (Page) but what for multiple models that I want to Alias, testimonial, pages, specific jobs, ...

Comment: isn't it possible to create a column that must be unique over all tables?

Comment: you could do ensure the uniqueness across models with a custom validation method. It'd be a bit tricky, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this should work (if you don't mind doing a redirect, which in some ways seems preferable anyway):

```
get '*alias', to: redirect { |params, request| 
  object = Page.find_by_alias(params[:alias]) || Other.find_by_alias(params[:alias])
  Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.url_for(object)
}
```

Your way is probably better **if (and only if)** you don't need the routes to be updated dynamically (e.g., your solution won't have a path for a newly created `Page` object until you restart the application). You could call `Rails.application.reload_routes!` as part of an observation on your models, but that doesn't seem as clean.